# bluetooth chat only works with android sdk 3.0?

Tags: android, bluetooth, chat

As one of my first Android projects I downloaded Bluetooth Chat sample code from

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

and tried to build it. It seems I can only build the project with Android SDK 3.0 - when using SDK 2.2 there were compile time errors, certain classes were not found.

I am wondering if there is a version of Bluetooth Chat that is compatible with 2.2? The reason I'm asking is that my dev phone is running Android 2.2 (Tmobile Comet), and the apk built with 3.0 crashes on my dev phone.

Answer (score 3):

The SDK contains samples for different API versions. You can download the BluetoothChat app for Android 2.2 using the [SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html) by selecting the "Samples for SDK API 8". After downloading, you will find it in `samples/android-8/BluetoothChat` in the SDK directory.

Answer (score 0):

The BluetoothChat application [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html) specifies an API level of 6 in the AndroidManifest.  It is meant to be run on Android versions 2.0.1 and higher.

Make sure that you have downloaded at least the API 6 documentation and tools from Google if you are just running the BluetoothChat application directly.

**EDIT:**

It looks like the android site has updated code to use API 11 classes... not sure why.  [Here](http://code.google.com/p/sprime/source/browse/trunk/sprime-android/src/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChat.java?r=28)'s an old version of BluetoothChat.java I found on google code.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. However the current source code uses classes like android.app.ActionBar, which is not in 2.2   What I want to achieve is an app that works on 2.2, now when I load the app it just crashes without much detail...

Comment: wow, you're right.  sorry for assuming it was so simple an answer.  I've updated my post with an old BluetoothChat source link.

Comment: I've updated the post with the link of the old BluetoothChat.java, but have you tried downloading the samples from the AVD/SDK manager?  I can't remember, but I think BluetoothChat was in there for the lower-api samples.

Comment: I downloaded the API level 7 sample using SDK manager and it works. Thanks John!